# Apply CSS to Content Page in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, css

Normally when we are using Master/Content style pages, we apply the css to Master page so every page child of the master page can use the style but I don't want this,I want I wanna apply css to content page directly instead of master page. Where should I put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

that reference code ?

Thanks in advance by the way.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Normally I put a content placeholder in the head section of the master page. That way any content page can add extra css/js/etc references to the head of the page.

In your master page put the following

```
<head>
  ... title, meta tags, js and css links ...
  <asp:contentPlaceholder id="head" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Then in your pages you can include extra elements in the head using this

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="head" runat="server">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</asp:content>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate it a little bit more and show me a sample please ?

Answer (score 5):

Put a content placeholder in the head portion of your master page. Not all content pages will need to place anything in it but this particular content page can place the CSS file you want to link.

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply a style sheet to a content page only, it applies to the whole web page.

Comment: @atarikg: No, you can't. The browser has no concept of content pages, it couldn't limit the scope of the css to a content page even if it wanted to.