# Style sheets only for the content page of a Master page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page which has 10 content pages linked to it.
Now a CSS file attached to the Master page gets applied to the content page on its own.

If however, I want a different CSS file only for one of the content pages (and none of the master page CSS should apply to it). How to do it??

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117256/apply-css-to-content-page-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You can add that style to a placeholder of the specific page not the masterpage

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Detail.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Detail" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/styles/style.css")%>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: By doing this we can apply different stylesheets to individual content pages , is it?

Comment: But I also want that the CSS in the master page do not apply to this psrticular content page?

@Ryu doing what u said solves half the problem :(

Comment: Sorry, I didnt see that part. Probably it will be easier to create another master page :| or you can do that by javascript. You can add styles on the master page by looking at a global javascript variable(add style if true/false). Then you can override this global variable any inner page that is using the master page