# Styles are not working for Content page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm facing a problem when our application is deployed in IIS. The styles are not applying to the content page but everything was working fine when I was running it through VS 2010. 
This is what I have given in the master page.

`<link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

The above code which I have specified will apply only for the Home page which is in the root directory but when I navigate to so other module styles are not applying to those page which are inside other folder.

I searched in Google and I tried many options like

```
<link href="./Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    @import 'Styles/style.css'; </style>
```

None of the above things are working even for home page also which used to work before. Please let me know some suggestions so I can proceed further.

Comment: try correcting the path by removing the beginning `..` and `~` from the href. A Url starting from `/` is considered to be starting from the root of the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1117256/217757

Comment: I tried using just `/` That is also not working.

Comment: @Naveed Butt The duplicate question has a answer like, need to place a place holder in head section. That means I need to add all the styles in all the pages ?

Comment: Where have you hosted the application on IIS or running through IIS Express ?

Comment: @Naveed Butt Hosted in IIS 7

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43726/discussion-between-naveed-butt-and-nuthan-gowda)

Answer (score 0):

```
<head runat="server">
<link href="~/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

it will work and load your css on every page

Answer (score 0):

try with adding the root/domain in a dynamic way before the styles folder in ur code.